# printing array out of bounds java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, indexing, bounds

i have an array of objects looking like this:

> 1: [volvo, 200] , [jaguar, 900]
>      2: [bmw, 300]
>   3: [skoda, 100] ,
>   [(no input)] , [(no input)]

---

this is my method to print only the areas with value (with some formating inside but it is not the issue). get an out of bound error... what do i need to do? thank you!

```
        public static void printMat(Car[][] carMat){
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        while ((carMat[row][column] != null)){
            System.out.printf("( %-8s : %,9d )", carMat[row][column].getName(), carMat[row][column].getPrice());
            if (column == carMat[row].length - 1){
                System.out.print("\n");
                row++;
                column = 0;
            } else {
                column++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked if you are going off the end of the current row, which is good, but you haven't checked if you have run out of rows.

After `row++`, add in a check to see if `row` has gone off the end of the `carMat` array.

```
if (row >= carMat.length)
    break;
```

That assumes that you have at least one row.  You may want to check if you have at least one row before you even enter the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int row = 0; row < car.length; row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < car[row].length; column++){
        //print statement
        if(column == car[row].length - 1){
             System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation uses a pair of `for` loops, the outer one cares only for the length of the array in rows, the inner one cares only for the length of the row.

I do, however, find your single loop implementation interesting from a performance standpoint.

Ben